# Reversing a vector using functions

Tags: c++

I'm trying to reverse a vector using functions but whenever I run the program it terminates and outputs nothing. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void reverseavector(vector<int>& vec)
{

    for (int i = vec.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        cout << vec[i];
    }
}

int main()
{

    int input;
    vector<int> vect;

    cout << "Enter  values to reverse the vector" << endl;
    cin >> input;

    for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); ++i) {
        vect.push_back(input);
    }
    reverseavector(vect);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code before posting. You can use a simple [tool](http://format.krzaq.cc/) where you just paste your code, and press "Format".

Comment: Your vector is empty when you declare it, so you never enter the loop in `main`. As a result, there's nothing in the reversed vector to print.

Comment: Can you try `while (cin >> input) { vect.push_back(input); }`

Comment: In the question code `cin >> input;` would read a single integer not multiple and your loop: `for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); ++i) {` is not entered because the vector size is 0. Also even if the vector size were greater than zero don't you think you want to add as many values as the user typed instead of some other number of copies of the 1 value you read from the user.

Comment: General rule of thumb. Write less code at a time. Write a few lines, just enough to do one testable thing. Compile and test that one thing with every different type of input you can think of. Do not proceed so long as there are compiler errors, compiler warnings you do not understand and accept, or failed test cases.  When that one thing works perfectly, write  more code, but just enough to add one more testable thing. Compile, test, and proceed when that one thing is working perfectly. Then write one more thing. Repeat as necessary.

Comment: Do not let errors build up. Do not waste your time adding to code that may not work because odds are good that fixing that one early bug will make all the code after it worthless.

Comment: *"outputs nothing"* -- are you accurately describing your symptoms? I would think your program outputs `Enter  values to reverse the vector` before terminating. (Small details can be important when debugging.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you declared the following statement:

```cpp
vector<int> vect;
```

This statement means that a vector of integers named `vect` get created, but you didn't specify a size for it, therefore when the following loop is reached:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); ++i){
    vect.push_back(input);
}
```

`vect.size()` return `0` because you didn't specify a size for `vect`, therefore the loop never gets executed. Because the condition is false.

Answer (score 1):

I made some changes to the code you have. Take a look:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void reverseavector(vector<int>& vec)
{

    for (int i = vec.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        cout << vec[i];
    }
}

int main()
{

    int input;
    vector<int> vect;
    bool stop = false;      // This bool will keep allow the while loop to keep prompting the user to enter a number until the input is -1

    while (stop == false)
    {
        cout << "Enter a value to the vector to be reversed, or -1 to stop entering values" << endl;
        cin >> input;
        vect.push_back(input);
        if (input == -1)
        {
            stop = true;
        }
    }
    reverseavector(vect);

    return 0;
}
```

The main thing about your code is that you needed a way to loop taking values into input. There are other ways to do this, but this was the first one I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

When you run

```
vector<int> vect;

cout << "Enter  values to reverse the vector" << endl;
cin >> input;

for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); ++i)
```

`vect.size()` remains at 0, because the vector is empty. So, `i < vect.size()` remains false, and the loop doesn't enter.

So, `reverseavector` gets an empty vector and outputs nothing.